# One viewController Rotate method

Tags: ios, swift

Okay this has been bugging me for quite some time now. I have an app that is locked in portrait mode. There is one viewController that I designate to play a video. I want that one viewController to be able to go in landscape mode. I tried overriding the shouldAutoRotate as well as the app delegate function/method. None of that seems to be working. Below is my curret viewController can anyone help me?

I looked at those other questions and they are not working for me. I don't want to force it into landscape mode. I just want free rotation in this one screen while everything else is locked in portrait.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class EventPromoVideoPlayer: UIViewController {
    public var eventKey = ""

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    //URL of promo video that is about to be played
    private var videoURL: URL
    // Allows you to play the actual mp4 or video
    var player: AVPlayer?
    // Allows you to display the video content of a AVPlayer
    var playerController : AVPlayerViewController?

    init(videoURL: URL) {
        self.videoURL = videoURL
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(_:)))
        downSwipe.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)


        //Setting the video url of the AVPlayer
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        guard player != nil && playerController != nil else {
            return
        }
        playerController!.showsPlaybackControls = false
        // Setting AVPlayer to the player property of AVPlayerViewController
        playerController!.player = player!
        self.addChildViewController(playerController!)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController!.view)
        playerController!.view.frame = view.frame
        // Added an observer for when the video stops playing so it can be on a continuous loop
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player!.currentItem)
        //TODO: Need to fix frame of x and y
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }

    // Allows the video to keep playing on a loop
    @objc fileprivate func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
        if self.player != nil {
            self.player!.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player!.play()
        }
    }


    @objc func swipeAction(_ swipe: UIGestureRecognizer){
        if let swipeGesture = swipe as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
                print("Swiped right")
                break
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
                print("Swiped Down")
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                break
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("Swiped left")
                break
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                print("Swiped up")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wait why did I get a downvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Presenting a view controller in landscape right from a view controller supporting only portrait mode after rotating the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002477/ios-presenting-a-view-controller-in-landscape-right-from-a-view-controller-supp)

Comment: because none of them are working?

Comment: I dont want to force it into landscape mode. I want free rotation for that screen. Before being a stickler maybe read my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: I hate when people come on here and try to make people feel dumb or downvote questions for no reason. If you feel like there is another question just post the link and tell me to look at the answer. I will decide if it helps and then thank you. But don't be mean you get no points for that. @dfd